# How many square integers less than $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $S(n)$ be the number of positive square integers less than $n$, e.g.

\begin{bmatrix}
n & S(n) \\
\hline
1 & 0 \\
2& 1 \\
3& 1 \\
4& 1 \\
5 & 2 \\
6& 2 \\
7& 2 \\
8& 2 \\
9& 2 \\
10& 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Is there a simple formula for $S(n)$ as a function of $n$? I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) applied to $\sqrt{n-1}$ :

$$S(n) = \lfloor \sqrt {n-1} \rfloor$$

Explation: $k^2 < n \iff k^2 \leq n-1 \iff k \leq \sqrt{n-1}$.

Comment: Alternatively $\lceil \sqrt {n} \rceil -1$.